# What is the difference between 幸せ, 倖せ and 仕合わせ?

Tags: meaning, nuances, homonyms

There are several ways to write the word しあわせ:

> 幸{しあわ}せ
>
> 倖{しあわ}せ
>
> 仕合{しあ}わせ

I would like to know what are the different nuances between them, and when is it appropriate to use each of them. For what is worth, I also asked the [same question in HiNative](https://hinative.com/questions/24549487?created_two_questions_tickets_added=true).

Comment: I don't know how HiNative works, but it appears that your question was mistakenly tagged as being about Chinese as spoken in Taiwan. It also seems to have attracted a largely nonsensical AI answer already.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel looks like the AI answer is a built-in feature of HiNative, similar to Quora. The language tagging is the poster's fault though, perhaps that's why no one has answered it...

Comment: Maybe OP is thinking Japanese and Chinese are the same language...? While Japanese and Chinese use the same script (kanji), they are grammatically different.

Answer (score 1):

幸せ is the default kanji which you should use 99% of the time. 倖せ and 仕合わせ are rare variant spellings that are reserved for creative writing. It's fine for a lyricist or novelist to use such spellings, but ordinary people should generally avoid them. See: [Why do authors choose to use obscure/old ways to write words?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90207/5010)